# Target browser size with CSS only

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is there a CSS selector for the size of the browser. So I can style elements if the browser is greater than 500px for instances.

My target browser is IE9 & IE10 in standards mode **only**; so I am only concerned about these two browsers.

Comment: What on earth is "browser size"?

Comment: @BoltClock READ AS: size of the `body` element, thought it was pretty clear myself - I guess not!

Comment: It was clear to me Ben. PoeHah's answer is slightly incorrect. Read up on responsive [web] design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use media queries, like so:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) { your css goes here }
```

Comment: @Ben Which you can refer to as responsiveness! :]

Comment: Are these fully supported by IE9+ in standards mode, or are there some typical IE qwerks?

Comment: @Ben: Yep, should be fine in IE9

Answer (score 1):

can't you just use css [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) for this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a selector in CSS for judging the size of one's screen.  But I also wouldn't go the Javascript route if you don't have to.  Perhaps you should look more into CSS media queries.

> CSS 3 enhances support for media-dependent style sheets by letting
>   style sheets be more precisely labeled.  A media query consists of a
>   media type and at least one expression that limits the style sheets'
>   scope by using media features, such as width, height, and color. 
>   Media queries let the presentation of content be tailored to a
>   specific range of output devices without having to change the content
>   itself.

**References:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries/

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/